# How do I look into session keys on production in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, session-variables, session-cookies

From my understanding, session keys and values are probably protected to maintain for security reasons, but my app currently uses session to store the UI state of a component so that the component is displayed the same way if the page is refreshed. I notice that this is working properly in staging and locally, but not in production. Is there a way I can see this through chrome dev tools somewhere on production?

Comment: is your app hosted on herkou?

Comment: no it's not :ll

Comment: hmm ok. I was going to suggest putting in `puts` statements in your controller actions to log the session variables in question (i.e. `puts "#{session[:variable_name]}"`) and then looking at the `heroku logs --tail` to see what was printed out